# MongodB CPU and memory utilization is low yet queries taking time to execute

Tags: query-performance, mongodb

I have 3 replica set instances running on different machines. Primary has CPU utilization of 20% and memory usage of 50% yet sometimes there are spike in in random queries which takes several seconds to fetch document. I thought it could be because we were querying on unindexed fields but then I found queries which are only fetching the document based on _id or some other field which is indexed and sometimes reaching 20s to retrieve the document. I have searched a lot but haven't found any lead on what might be causing this issue.

Qurey example

```
db.users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("...") })
```

sometimes this is also taking 20s

Comment: An example of the query that's taking 20 seconds to execute would probably be helpful to add to your post.

Comment: @J.D. added example query

Comment: If you do db.users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("...") }).explain() what is the result... What part of query is slowest?  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/

Comment: .explain() is a good start. It's also good to turn on profiling, to have slow query statistics captured and check the output for further clues. If it doesn't show any clue, check IO on your storage.